# Stack overflow error with recursion function to find number within an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a program that is fairly simple. The program simply creates an array of size 5000 and finds a user inputted key using recursion. I completed that part of the program and it works as intended finding any number from 0 - 4999. However I also need to create an error message for if the user's number is not found. For instance if I try to enter a negative number or a number greater than the size of the array. However when I try this I get the following error:

[image: Error Message]

I also have this warning message on my main function:

[image: Warning Message]

Here is the code that I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int recursiveCount = 0;
int lowVal = 0;
int recursiveLinearSearch(int array[], int key, const int size, bool& methodStatus);

int main()
{
    const int size = 5000;
    int key; 
    int array[size]; 
    bool methodstatus = false;

    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
        array[count] = count; 
    }
    cout << "Please enter a key to search for: ";
    cin >> key;

    int index = recursiveLinearSearch(array, key, size,  methodstatus);
    
    if (index >= 0) {
        cout << "Found at position " << index << ", it took " << recursiveCount << " recursions.\n";
    }

    else {
        cout << "Error, not found\n";
    }

    return 0; 

}

int recursiveLinearSearch(int array[],int key, const int size, bool & methodStatus) {

    int highVal = size; 
    recursiveCount++;
    

    int midVal = (highVal + lowVal) / 2; 

    do {
        if (key < array[midVal]) {
            recursiveLinearSearch(array, key, midVal, methodStatus);
        }
        else if (key > array[midVal]) {
            lowVal = midVal;
            recursiveLinearSearch(array, key, highVal, methodStatus);
        }
        else if (key < 0) {
            return -1; 
        }
        else if (key > 5000) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            methodStatus = true; 
        }


    } while (methodStatus == false);


    return key;
    
}
```

Comment: Searching an array using recursion is utterly wrong. If this was a homework assignment, you need to find a better C++ instructor.

Comment: `recursiveLinearSearch` -- What you wrote is not a linear search -- it is attempting to do a binary search.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've noticed that often students will be set HW to demonstrate a specific concept, but the problem used is completely unsuitable. Quite unfortunate, really :(

Answer (score 1):

What if key small enough, so `if (key < array[midVal]) {` is always true. There's an infinite recursion and therefore stack overflow.